# how to use automapper for a ViewModel with an IEnumerable<T> property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, viewmodel, automapper, action-filter

I'm trying to follow [Jimmy Bogard's advice for automapping through an actionfilter](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/06/29/how-we-do-mvc-view-models.aspx) (which works great in most cases). But what if I have a custom viewmodel with a collection property that I want mapped? For example,

```
public class WidgetSearchViewModel
{
    public WidgetSearchOptionsViewModel Options { get; set; }
    public GenericListPagerViewModel Pager { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<WidgetSearchResultModel> Results { get; set; }
}
```

The Results property comes from the repository as an IEnumerable of domain entities, which I want to convert to WidgetSearchResultModel instances using automapper. The problem is that I will need to construct a WidgetSearchViewModel in the controller to populate the Options and Pager properties. How can I use an AutoMapper ActionFilter to populate the Results property OnActionExecuted? Is it even possible, or am I going to need to puta Mapper.Map call in the controller and bootstrap all of the mappings in my unit tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automapper already has build in support for mapping between any nested set that implements IEnumerable.  If you define the parent and child property mappings automapper will map the nested collections just fine.

Automapper can also handle mapping anything to anything if you are implement a CustomTypeConvertor: http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Also, a unit test can call Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); which tests your configuration will work.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I'm wondering though, how would I write my controller code if there is no domain/entity equivalent to the WidgetSearchViewModel class example in my question? The controller needs to populate the Options & Pager properties, for which there are no entity equivalents. Do I need to create a matching DTO class that has an IEnumerable<WidgetSearchResultDomainEntity> Results property and populate that in the controller, then have Automapper convert? Or am I better off leaving the mapping in the controller for scenarios like this? How would you do it?